# how can I call a function of component2 contained in the html view of component 1?

Tags: angular

I have 2 components called `principal` and `menu`. in the `menu` component I have a json object and an html code in which when I click on an element I would expect to call a function contained in the `principal` component. I want that when I click on this function, the selected object shows in the `principal` component. I know that this can be done in a single component, but I am trying to create the scenario of a real problem that I have. Thank you.

app.component

```html
<menu></menu>
<principal></principal>
```

menu.component

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'menu',
template: `Select a animal: <br> <button *ngFor="let item of aAnimals" (click)="getAnimal(item);" style="display:block;">{{item.animal}}</button>`,
styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class MenuComponent  {
 aAnimals=
 [
  {"animal":"cat"},
  {"animal":"dog"},
  {"animal":"horse"}
 ]
 constructor(){

}
```

principal.component

```ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'principal',
  template: `<h1>animal selected: {{animal}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class PrincipalComponent  {
  animal:any;
  constructor(){

  }
  public getAnimal(item) {
    alert(item)
    this.animal=item.animal;
  }

}
```

this is my code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paamqn

This answers my question. One last doubt. In my real code, am I calling `<menu>` within the `principal` component how could I make it work? what would it change? I can no longer use #principal.

instead of

```
<principal #principal></principal>
```

directly the code html of `principal` component

```
<!-- html of principal.component.html -->
<menu (callPrincipalMethod)="principal.getAnimal($event)"></menu>
<h1>animal selected: {{animal}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by binding each other with `EventEmitter`.

```html
<menu (callPrincipalMethod)="principal.getAnimal($event)"></menu>
<principal #principal></principal>
```

menu.component:

```ts
import { Component, Input,  Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
selector: 'menu',
template: `Select a animal: <br> <button *ngFor="let item of aAnimals" (click)="getAnimal(item);" style="display:block;">{{item.animal}}</button>`,
styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class MenuComponent  {
 @Output()
 callPrincipalMethod = new EventEmitter()

 aAnimals=
 [
  {"animal":"cat"},
  {"animal":"dog"},
  {"animal":"horse"}
 ]
 constructor(){}

 getAnimal(item) {
  this.callPrincipalMethod.emit(item)
 }
}
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ko2d58

**Update**

If `menu` component is inside `principal` component, simply omit the principal in `principal.getAnimal($event)`

```html
<!-- html of principal.component.html -->
<menu (callPrincipalMethod)="getAnimal($event)"></menu>
<h1>animal selected: {{animal}}</h1>
```